# What is difference between search in Magento2 community Vs enterprise

Tags: magento2, search, elasticsearch, opensearch

What is the difference between search in the Magento2  community Vs enterprise?

Comment: hey this did not consider to be discussed here, please check this link for your answer https://serverguy.com/magento/magento-community-vs-enterprise-edition/

Comment: Hi Charlie, I want to know only search changes. This post is showing Magento CE vs EE difference and no Search change is included in this posts!